# pandas- grouping and aggregating consecutive rows with same value in column

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a pandas DataFrame from a long list of datetime ranges pulled from a database, each range with a label.  The dates are ordered such that the start date of one row, is the end date of the row before.  A workable example is here:

```
import pandas as pd

bins = [{'start': '2020-01-12 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-13 00:00:00', 'label': 't3'},
        {'start': '2020-01-13 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-13 07:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-13 07:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-13 15:30:00', 'label': 't1'},
        {'start': '2020-01-13 15:30:00', 'end': '2020-01-14 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-14 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-14 07:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-14 07:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-14 15:30:00', 'label': 't1'},
        {'start': '2020-01-14 15:30:00', 'end': '2020-01-15 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-15 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-15 07:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-15 07:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-15 15:30:00', 'label': 't1'},
        {'start': '2020-01-15 15:30:00', 'end': '2020-01-16 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-16 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-16 07:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-16 07:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-16 15:30:00', 'label': 't1'},
        {'start': '2020-01-16 15:30:00', 'end': '2020-01-17 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-17 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-17 07:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-17 07:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-17 15:30:00', 'label': 't1'},
        {'start': '2020-01-17 15:30:00', 'end': '2020-01-18 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'},
        {'start': '2020-01-18 00:00:00', 'end': '2020-01-19 00:00:00', 'label': 't2'}]
bins_df = pd.DataFrame(bins)
```

Notice that some labels are repeated consecutively, for example, the 4th and 5th row, have the same label.  Thus, the label `'t2'` applies to the range from `2020-01-13 15:30:00` to `2020-01-14 07:00:00`.  Using pandas, how can I group/aggregate consecutive rows with the same label, and take the minimum `start`, and maximum `end` to combine consecutive date ranges with the same label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First we use `Series.shift` with `Series.cumsum` to make a group indicator for each consecutive `label` value.

Then we use `groupby.agg` with `min` and `max`.

```
label_groups = bins_df['label'].ne(bins_df['label'].shift()).cumsum()

df = (
    bins_df.groupby(label_groups).agg({'start':'min', 'end':'max', 'label':'first'})
           .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```
                 start                 end label
0  2020-01-12 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00    t3
1  2020-01-13 00:00:00 2020-01-13 07:00:00    t2
2  2020-01-13 07:00:00 2020-01-13 15:30:00    t1
3  2020-01-13 15:30:00 2020-01-14 07:00:00    t2
4  2020-01-14 07:00:00 2020-01-14 15:30:00    t1
5  2020-01-14 15:30:00 2020-01-15 07:00:00    t2
6  2020-01-15 07:00:00 2020-01-15 15:30:00    t1
7  2020-01-15 15:30:00 2020-01-16 07:00:00    t2
8  2020-01-16 07:00:00 2020-01-16 15:30:00    t1
9  2020-01-16 15:30:00 2020-01-17 07:00:00    t2
10 2020-01-17 07:00:00 2020-01-17 15:30:00    t1
11 2020-01-17 15:30:00 2020-01-19 00:00:00    t2
```

Comment: Thanks for both the code example, and the explanation of what it does.  Worked beautifully.

Comment: In latest pandas I needed to add .dropna() before the .cumsum() - otherwise all group indicators were NA